# How to add a search feature in jsf page

Tags: java, search, jsf, netbeans

I want to add a search box that will return results from a mysql database. Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass the search text to a query and return the result?

For example, you would pass the search String to some persistence layer (JDBC, JPA etc.) and use the correct query syntax for that layer.

A more flexible yet more complicated approach would be to use a search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and create a search index for your database.

Comment: that is a good idea...do u know of any tutorials that I can look at to get me started on this?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I didn't use any online tutorials myself, so I can't tell of any good one. However, the first hit on `MySQL JPA tutorial` gives [this first hit](http://www.javaguicodexample.com/javawejsfjpamysqlbdatabase12ver2.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: This should help get me started. Thanks a lot for your help.